# eonasdan datetimepicker century threshold

Tags: eonasdan-datetimepicker

Any tips would be welcome: I need the datetimepicker to transform a date earlier than 1969 to that year in the 20th century. So if I enter 12-12-69 the datetimepicker transforms that into 12-12-1969. Entering 12-12-68 though is transformed into 12-12-2068. I assume this is done in moment.js, but I may be mistaken. If it is done in moment.js anyone have an idea where to look to change the threshhold for this automagic transformation? I'd rather change it in the library than use parseInputDate, but if anyone has an example on usage of parseInputDate, please share. I have found that the date already has been changed automagically as ddescribed above when I try and access the date-object via:

```
$('#datefrom').on('dp.change',function(e) { console.log(e.date); });
```

I need to access the date object B4 this happens. It works to set a onchange="dostuff()" inline on the input field itself, but that sort of feels wrong, as I want to handle this in one place in the datetimepicker and not in 50 places inline.

Comment: OK, I found where in Moment.js this happens: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/ - search for heading 'Parsing two digit years'. It is the Moment.js function 'parseTwoDigitYear' that now has a threshold of >68 to change two-digit years into 19XX and 68 and below becomes 20XX. Now my question is how to leverage this knowledge into a function in the DateTimePicker? So as to be adjustable ;-)